# Do 32GB DDR4 SO-DIMM ECC memory modules exist?

Tags: ssd, storage, pci-express, nvme, ecc

I'd like to buy a couple modules for a laptop, but I can't seem to find any when I search on Google.

For example, I tried searching for things like "32gb" "pcie" "nvme" "ecc" "ssd"`and`"32gb" "m.2" "ecc" "so-dimm" or various similar permutations, but had no luck.

The specs for the [Intel Xeon E-2186M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134859/intel-xeon-e-2186m-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz.html) processor state that it can support up to 64GB of ECC memory.

However, I can't find any 32GB ECC modules for the two slots in the laptop.

Does it not exist?

Comment: 32 GB DDR4 modules exist but very few motherboards actually support it.  I am not aware of any 32 GB ECC DDR4 modules at all.  I am unaware of any laptop motherboard that would support that density.

Comment: Just today, I read the announcement for 32 GB sticks CORSAIR VENGEANCE LPX DDR4-3000 ... these are full-size standard desktop DIMMs.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Those are the only module other than Samsung I am aware of.  ASUS has some special support to achieve compatibly at that density, none of the modules I know exist are ECC though.  **32 GB DDR4 modules are a product just hitting the market this year.**. Most manufacturers just announced their products in June.

Comment: Your CPU may support it, but double check that your motherboard can as well, as Ramhound has said.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer, since I am unaware of any 32 GB DDR4 ECC modules on the market, but any answer I could submit, would be outdated in 6 months and impossible without knowing which motherboard you have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will become outdated quickly.

Comment: I wonder how soon 32GB ECC SODIMM sticks will be out.

Comment: Dell XPS 15 has Xeon variant when customizing notebook during ordering process (UK webshop), they also offer ECC memory. It's all overpriced - however it answers remarks from others that it doesn't exist. Also I dislike advertizing manufacturers, but I had to in order to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According what I see and read - they do exist, [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UWRP.jpg) a SODIMM based on Samsung chips and [this 64GB pair](https://www.compuram.biz/memory/generic-ram-modules/so-dimm/260pin/series/ddr4-2666-pc4-21300-ecc-so-dimm/64gb-dual-channel-memory-kit-x97ea.htm). CPU needs support for ECC so Intel specs are your best friend.

Notebook with [i9-9980HK](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i9-processors/i9-9980hk.html) wouldn't work according Intel but notebook with [E-2286M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192993/intel-xeon-e-2286m-processor-16m-cache-2-40-ghz.html) would work just fine with ECC modules. I believe many manufacturers offer option for mobile Xeon while configuring notebook.

It is also worth noting that the [Xeon E-2286M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192993/intel-xeon-e-2286m-processor-16m-cache-2-40-ghz.html), mirrors the Core [i9-9980HK](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i9-processors/i9-9980hk.html) in almost every aspect including the price, but swaps the overclocking functionality for the ability to use ECC memory and maybe vPro feature depending on generation or model.

As overclocking isn't relevant for mobile CPUs, they overheat and throttle anyway, mine goes up to 70 celsius, I see big fat reason of using ECC especially with bigger modules.

Now, from my humble experience - I work with huge files (10GB-20GB) and I have 2x32GB, so when extracting content, 7zip sometimes shows archive errors, which don't exist (tested on desktop), so after playing with power management settings, parking cores to keep it cooler, things get better, but ECC would give me some peace of mind !

I never had problem with ECC server memory and finally I start to see reason for insane numerous ECC RDIMM options such as RAM temperature throttling, sensors, error logs, etc...

Talking to other users having similar configs, they occasionally have problems, crash BSOD pointing to memory trap event (dump analysis), etc. All-mighty, lengthy hardware tests pass well (intel burn, memtest blah blah) - so shortly yes to ECC.

Comment: Nice find! I guess it isn't common yet, at time of writing.

Comment: no, not common yet. Powerful notebooks that can't be cooled as servers while notebooks have sub-optimal cooling, so at least don't save on memory and CPU, go with something which has sensors and protection... it's not server it's notebook that stays on the bed, while cooling is beneath (another monstrosity that survived for years) - but seeing 300 views of your question, it looks like people are stuck with cheap pentinum and 8 gb ram forever.

Answer (score 0):

There are SODIMM 32GB memory sticks. They are not common and expensive. For example Hynix/Hyunday (P/N HMAA4GS7AJR8N-VK) I have one running on my HP Z2 mini G4 (Xeon based machine). They are expensive though (from $188, from China, to £280 in the UK... and not immediately available). I am wondering if it is worth forking out on another to make it a pair and move my workstation to 64GB RAM... The black Diamond I don't know them.